# IOS In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

My IOS App have In-App Purchase build on it . the Problem is if you buy the app now and remove the app and want install it again you would have to pay again . even if you want to install the app on another device using the same App store account it ask you to pay again

is there anyone have such problem before and how top fix that ?

Answer (score 3):

The StoreKit framework allows you to restore purchases for users without having to pay multiple times for a purchase.

Look at the Store Kit documentation for Restoring Transactions.

The restoration process requires the user to log in with their iTunes Account, so that the system knows their purchase history.

As long as you implement the restore process and provide a UI for a user to do so, you users should never have to pay more than once for a purchase within your app, even if they uninstall the app and reinstall it on a different device.

Comment: StoreKit only provides recovery functionality for non-consumable items (and to some extend for subscriptions). So for consumable products, recovering using restoreCompletedTransactions will not deliver any transactions in your case. Any handling of restoring information about consumable products must be done within your app and/or server.

Comment: Yeah, what he said ;)

Comment: For Consumable products you can look into options of storing data in keychain (They persist in keychain even after deletion of the app)

Comment: @Diptesh yeah, that's a solution for delete and reinstall, but not between different devices (unless iCloud keychain is being used, which can't be guaranteed).